# Not fetching any data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this ajax request where i try to find some tags and add it to search results

The problems comes when i try with my php script to find something then it doesn't find anything

```
<div>
<form action="search()" method="post">
    <label for="tagsearch">Search tags: </label>
    <input type="text" id="tagSearch" name="tagsearch"/>
    <input type="button" id="tagenter" value="Add tag"/>
</div>
<div id="tagHolder">
    <!--Tags here-->
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function search(){
            var tag=$("tagSearch").val();

            if(tag!=""){
                $("#tagHolder").html();
                $.ajax({
                   type:"post",
                    url:"gettag.php",
                    data:"tag="+encodeURIComponent(tag),
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#tagHolder").html(data);
                        $("#tagSearch").val("");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        $("#tagenter").click(function(){
            search();
        });

        $('#tagSearch').keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                search();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code is the ajax request.

This is the php script

```
//Connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

//Check if connection is up
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Couldn't connect". mysqli_connect_error($con);
}

$tag = $_POST["tag"];

$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '".$tag."'");
$found=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($found>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div>". $row['tag'] . "</div>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<div>No suggestions</div>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Im getting the "No suggestions" as search result. My guess is that the SQL query is wrong or the $found variable is wrong.

Comment: Let's see your HTML form. I see no `<form></form>` tags in your posted code. `$_POST["tag"]` is taken from a POST form method.

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but `data:"tag="+tag` is wrong. It should be `data:{tag:tag}` (preferred) or `data:"tag="+encodeURIComponent(tag)`.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://xkcd.com/327/ (you're leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks).

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The OP is using `type: "POST"` in their ajax call.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, yet shouldn't the `<input type="text" id="tagSearch" name="tagsearch"/>` etc. be wrapped in a form tag? Or does Ajax take care of all that?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: No, `ajax` doesn't require forms (or form elements) at all. In this case, the OP is using a form element, but only as a means of getting the value to send.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok thanks. Now, taken the OP's edit `<form action="search()"` can't just call `search()` like that. `function search(){...}` which stands at being a contributing factor. Plus, a missing `</form>` tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Quite true. The click on `tagEnter` would work, though. But yes, on browsers that submit the form when you press the Enter key in a text field if the text field is the only field, pressing the Enter key in that field would not have the desired effect. :-) The missing `</form>` tag probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @OP See the comments above, plus you have `name="tagsearch"` and `var tag=$("tagSearch").val();` - am under the impression that it's case-sensitive, so try also changing all `tagSearch` to `tagsearch` or `name="tagsearch"` to `name="tagSearch"`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: `$("#tagSearch")` looks for the `id`, not the `name`. The `id` has the capital `S`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it. In regards to your comment further up `data:{tag:tag}` - Am under the impression that since OP is using the named form element `name="tagsearch"` then the POST `$_POST["tag"]` shouldn't that be `data:{tag:tagsearch}`? I'm just confused as to the relation of the POST element. POST usually looks for an element of the same name. I stand at being wrong about `data:{tag:tagsearch}` though. Ajax isn't my strong point, but PHP/SQL are.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: We're not posting the form, so nothing related to the form matters. What `data: {tag: tag}` does is pass `ajax` an object with a property called `tag` whose value is taken from the `tag` variable. Perhaps a bit more clearly: `var foo = "bar"; $.ajax({url: "/page", type: "post", data: {prop: foo}});` would pass `prop` to the page with the value `"bar"`: `echo $_POST['prop']` would show `bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several significant problems here.

1. As Jeff [cryptically points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26087012/157247), you're not getting your value from `tagSearch` correctly, because `$("tagSearch")` looks for an element with the *tag name* `tagSearch`, not the `id` `tagSearch`. To use the `id`, add the `#` to your selector: `var tag=$("#tagSearch").val();` This is the primary cause of the problem you've described, but keep reading, there's a lot more to do.
2. **You're wide open to SQL injection attacks.** [Humorous example](http://xkcd.com/327/):

   [image]

   Read more about them [here](http://bobby-tables.com/), and about how to defend against them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
3. In your `ajax` call, `data:"tag="+tag` is wrong. It should be `data:{tag:tag}` (preferred) or `data:"tag="+encodeURIComponent(tag)`.  With your original code, if `tag` contains any character that isn't directly valid in URI-encoding (loosely, in a URL), your PHP page won't quite receive what you're sending. When use use an object (my first example), jQuery will handle encoding it for you; otherwise, do the encoding yourself with `encodeURIComponent`.
4. As [Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) helpfully points out, Your form action is wrong, and some browsers *will* try to use it when the user presses the Enter key in your text field. It should be `action="javascript:search()"`, not just `action="search()"`. The latter will be treated as a URL.
5. Also as [Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) points out, You probably wanted to close your `form` element with a `</form>` above the `</div>`.

---

**Error checking**

You're also not checking for any errors in your code, such as [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Those are important tools you should use during development.

Comment: Ah, OP accepted the answer. Glad to see it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`var tag=$("tagSearch").val();` 
try `var tag=$("#tagSearch").val();`
if you want to select which id is "tagSearch", use $("#tagSearch")
There is more about selector in jquery
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: This is probably correct. To make it a good answer, say *why*, not just *what*.